# A HREF URL won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the following link to work.

```
<a href='#' onclick='window.open(" | &ESPP_Info_URL | ");return false;'>Employee Stock Purchase Plan Information</a>
```

Basically the &ESPP_Info_URL variable takes in a url so that the code below looks like...

```
<a onclick="window.open(https://...);return false;" href="#">Employee Stock Purchase Plan Information</a>
```

But when I click the url it just refreshes the page.  Does anyone know how to get this to access the link within the window.open function?

Comment: you can create a function to open link in new window, then call it in your link `onclick` event

Comment: The syntax you show (`| &ESPP_Info_URL |`)does not look like standard HTML/Javascript. Are you using a framework of some kind that maniuplates the HTML?

Comment: Do a view source to see what code is actually being generated for the `onclick` - I suspect that it's not outputting what you think it is and is probably causing a Javascript error (check the error console in your browser).

Comment: you cannot concatenate the variable in inline javascript..

Comment: wtf why aren't you just putting the url in the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You need wrap url with in single quotes `'` - `window.open('YOUR URL HERE')`

```
<a onclick="window.open('YOUR URL HERE');return false;" href="#">Employee Stock Purchase Plan Information</a>
```

Comment: how would I write that with the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extended version with more dynamic functionality, jic:
http://jsfiddle.net/ofnh7gke/

And the smaller version:
http://jsfiddle.net/rqf3s72n/

**Javascript**

```
var sites = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.github.com'];
document.getElementById('btnStockPurchasePlan').onclick = function(){
    window.open(sites[0],'_parent');
    return false;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' id="btnStockPurchasePlan">Employee Stock Purchase Plan Information</a>
```